# Positioning a background image with CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to precisely position a background image with CSS? Code:

```
.content h2.productSpotlight {background:url(/images/spotlight.jpg) no-repeat; padding-left: 35px;}
```

I want to be able to move the image around so its more flush with the H2

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can give an offset position for the `background` property, for example:

```
background: url(/images/spotlight.jpg) no-repeat 10px 5px;
```

This will shift the background image 10px from the left corner and 5px from the top. You can also use negative values to shift in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

sure, the background properties include `background-position`. You can specify it separately as

```
background-position:20px 20px;
```

or as part of the combined syntax like

```
background:url(/images/spotlight.jpg) no-repeat 20px 20px;
```

See the [reference at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position).